# Post image file to RESTful Web Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blackberry

I'm trying to send an image file to a web service.

here's my code:

```
   ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;

        //String value = new String(data);
        String value= Base64OutputStream.encodeAsString(data, 0, data.length, false, false);

        value = "imgData=" + value;

        connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://localhost:50806/Send");
        int iResponseCode = 0;
        HttpConnection httpConn = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        if (connDesc != null)
        {

            try
            {
             byte[] theByteArray = value.getBytes();

                httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();

                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));

                //os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
                //os.write(theByteArray);
                DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream (httpConn.openOutputStream()); 
                printout.write(theByteArray);
                iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();        
             } 
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if(os != null)
                    os.close();

                if(httpConn != null){                    
                 httpConn.close();
                }
            }

        }
  return Integer.toString(iResponseCode);
```

A byte array represented the image file is passed into the method.

service signature:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]  
    public ActionResult Send(string imgData)
    {}
```

Any ideas on how to send this?

Thanks so much,
Dan

Comment: What does the REST service expect? A base64-encoded array?

Comment: After reading another post on a similar topic I changed my service to accept a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Base64-encoded string is probably going to be too large to pass as a URL parameter in a GET request.  Either the device or some proxy along the way may do something bad to the request.  It would be much safer using a POST request.  To do this, set the request as a POST with `httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST)` and then write all of the form parameters into the body of the request using `httpConn.openOutputStream()` (and possibly the [PostData](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/PostData.html) class)

Comment: Hey Marc, Thanks for the help. I've updated the code(see above). Does that look right to you? What would my web service's method signature look like? I'm not sure how to get the byte data. Thanks again.

Comment: The code looks good - you probably don't need to flush the OS since the call to httpConn.getResponseCode() will automatically flush it.  As for the webservice, can't really help there as it depends on the server platform, etc.  Basically though you just want to be able to read the bytes directly from the body - relatively easy to do in Java servlets, PHP, etc.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the reply. I'm using asp.net mvc. I can get everything to work when I'm sending smaller string values to the controller. but I can seem to get the post value. I've updated the code and included my controller's method signature. Let me know if anything doesn't look right :)  Thanks again, very much.

Comment: You should probably create a new Stackoverflow question for your server-side problem and tag it with "asp.net", etc. since this question has veered from the original BlackBerry client problem

Comment: Okay. that's a good idea. Thanks a lot for your help! Take care.